# How To Extract Information Using The Amazon API

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, extract, amazon-product-api

I am an amazon associate and would like to display a few specific products on my website, preferably with the use of the Amazon API.

I'm a complete beginner at this so not sure how to begin, or even if the information I want can be shown or not.

In basic terms I would like to extract & display the:

- Current Price
- Description
- Stock Availability ( In / Out )

More advanced options would primarily include:

- User Rating
- User Reviews
- A Preview Video / Audio / Gallery

Can anyone tell me if this is possible, **using PHP**, and of course where to begin with using the Amazon Services API

Answer (score 0):

This is supported.

Your question is broad, so I can only give you relevant links to help you get started:

- Main page of [Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html).
- [Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html).
- PHP library on [Github](https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io) 'based on PHP REST and SOAP (only V1)'.